# Buttons don't appear on phone

Tags: android, css, button

Take a look at [this sample site.](http://www.granthoneymoon.com/Most_insightful_posts.html)

Under the next button there should be 3 buttons (add, learn more, and report). In both IE and firefox they look great no matter how small the browser. But when I look on my samsung galaxy 3 those 3 buttons do not appear. Any idea why?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div ID="add_learn_wrapper"><div ID="add_learn_container"><div ID="add_learn_stretch"><div ID="add_learn">
<div class="add_learn_buttons">
<a href=#><img src="images/add-button-up.png" class="button"></a></div>
<div class="add_learn_buttons"><a href=#><img src="images/learn_more_button.png" class="button"></a></div>
<div class="add_learn_buttons"><a href=#><img src="images/report-button.png" class="button"></a>
</div></div></div></div></div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.button, .back_button {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.0s;
    transition: all 0.0s;
}

.button:active, .button:hover, .back_button:hover, .back_button:active {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
    transform: scale(0.95);
}

#add_learn_wrapper {
    width: 75%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
#add_learn_wrapper {
    width: 95%;
}   
}
#add_learn_container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 60%;
    max-width: 480px;
    min-width: 320px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
#add_learn_container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-width: 10px;
}   
}
#add_learn_stretch {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 54%;
    position: relative;
}
#add_learn {
    display: block;
    Position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

.add_learn_buttons {

    height: 32%;
    width: 100%;

}
.add_learn_buttons img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Are looking through a `WebView` or native browser?

Comment: It looks fine in native IE and firefox browsers on my PC (at all sizes). But when I try on my phone the buttons are completely gone!